# having trouble getting text from a text box to match a regular expression

Tags: jquery, regex, validation

No matter what I type into StreetAddress, it never matches the regex. Whether it be PO Box PO BOX po box. I can't seem to get this to work. Any ideas?

```
   function valPoBox(sender, args) {
        var hasPObox = new RegExp('\b[P|p]*(OST|ost)*\.*\s*[O|o|0]*(ffice|FFICE)*\.*\s*[B|b][O|o|0][X|x]\b');
        var StreetAddress = $('.streetaddress').val();

        if (StreetAddress.match(hasPObox)) {
            args.IsValid = false;

            sender.ErrorMessage = "Address must not contain P.O. Box";
//            $('.valPoBox').attr("ErrorMessage", sender.ErrorMessage);
        }
        else {
            args.IsValid = true;
        }
        $('.valPoBox').attr("errormessage", sender.ErrorMessage);
    }
```

Comment: replaced var hasPObox = new RegExp('\b[P|p]*(OST|ost)*\.*\s*[O|o|0]*(ffice|FFICE)*\.*\s*[B|b][O|o|0][X|x]\b');

with:
var hasPObox = /^[P|p]*(OST|ost)*\.*\s*[O|o|0]*(ffice|FFICE)*\.*\s*[B|b][O|o|0][X|x]\s*(\d.)*/gi;

It's now working. Sorry fellas!

Comment: The `i` flag ignores the case; you don't need all those UPPER|lower dupes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the whole regular expression is way too complicated:

```
var poBoxRegex = /po?(st)? *(office)? box/gi;
```

results:

```
"34 po box 333".match(poBoxRegex);
["po box"]
"34 postoffice box 333".match(poBoxRegex);
["postoffice box"]
"34 post office box 333".match(poBoxRegex);
["post office box"]
```

Comment: Unable to get value of the property 'match': object is null or undefined